# The Regular Expression, What the pattern should be to get these string for shortcode?

Tags: php, regex

The example shortcode is

```
[su_slider source="media: 11862,11864,11866,11863,11865,11861,11867" width="340" height="220" pages="no" autoplay="0"]
```

I would like to get 11862,11864,11866,11863,11865,11861,11867 form the shortcode with regular pattern and php

What's the pattern should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$shortcode = '[su_slider source="media: 11862,11864,11866,11863,11865,11861,11867" width="340" height="220" pages="no" autoplay="0"]';

preg_match('~ source="media: \K[^"]+~', $shortcode, $match);

var_dump($match[0]);
```

Output:

```
string(41) "11862,11864,11866,11863,11865,11861,11867"
```

Live [demo](https://ideone.com/xWoHNE).

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my times a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = '[su_slider source="media:11862,11864,11866,11863,11865,11861,11867" width="340" height="220" pages="no" autoplay="0"]';

$pattern = '/source="media:[\s]?([0-9,]+)\"/';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

If matched, the `$match[1]` is what you want.